# MongoDB to store vehicle tracking information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gis, postgis

I am building an app similar to Uber for tracking vehicles. Since the update frequency is so high (accounting for several users), I want to know the general practices involved for making writes faster to mongodb collection.

I am maintaining a database to store historical location information from all vehicles but it is bound to grow very fast once we go into production. I need to get the list of vehicles closest to a point. For this should I implement a separate table (with one row per vehicle) which gets updated after every update or there is better/faster way to do this using the existing table?

Answer (score 2):

Two separate collections would likely be the best option here.

A `vehicles` collection which includes the current location. It could even include the 50 most recent location entries, added with $push and $slice to not have unbounded array growth. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice

A `locationHistory` collection which includes all previous vehicle movements. You could index this by vehicle ID, and/or date.

One thing you for sure want to avoid is having an UNBOUNDED array inside a document.

{_id: ObjectID, VIN: String, 
 pastLocations: [{...unbounded array... }]
}

When mongodb allocates space for a new vehicle entry, it will use an average of the existing vehicle sizes to determine how much disk space to allocate. Having vastly different sizes of vehicle entries (some move more than others, or are newer etc) will negatively impact performance, and cause a lot more page faults.

The key here is that you're trying to avoid page faults. Keeping 50 entries of vehicle history (if they're just GPS coordinates) as a subdocument array isn't super huge. Keeping an entire year's worth of history that could be more than 1MB would be a big deal (heh) and cause page faults all the time when accessing different vehicles.

Comment: Is there a limit to number of inserts / updates mongodb can handle per second? 
In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fO83dyxa0Vo) video Curtis mentions that they discarded mongodb as they reached its limits soon after they went into production.

Answer (score 1):

I did some extensive data storage loading of 20 GB+ in MongoDB over couple of months (deployed latest stable version in Aug. 2014). I noticed that the database corrupted on Windows OS (using high performance storage - iSCI over fibre channel), so MongoDB service just stopped and could not be started. I can still reproduce the issue by reaching high data loads. I cannot recommend for MongoDB for any production deployment, I hope you can find a better DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Performance should get better on mongodb due to wiredtiger integration on the newest version. (Not stable yet:http://blog.mongodb.org/post/102461818738/announcing-mongodb-2-8-0-rc0-release-candidate-and)